# How to pause a for loop until the enter key is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for example

```
bool x = false;

if(press enter)
{
  x = true;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if(x == true)
    print (i);

  x = false;
}
```

code like that always give me 0 after enter pressed instead of the whole sequence 1,2,3...10.

I found three answer online, but all of them are not wrote in c#, I actually use it in Unity, so it has to be c#..

Comment: I would suggest you listen for keypress event, and if the key pressed is Enter, process your for loop.

Comment: Please explain, what do you expect at the output? If enter is presses: 1,2...,10 and if not 0,1,...,10?

Comment: I suggest you to use coroutines in such case instead of normal function

Comment: I mean 0,1,2,3...10, sorry

Comment: It will never reach 10 as it stands at the moment as the for loop will only run while `i` is less than 10.

Comment: 0,1,2,3...9 sorry, but that's not the point..

Comment: thank you @Deekshith Hegde Hegde, you are right

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(x == true)
        print(i);

    // This line is executed allways
    x = false;
}
```

So what happens is that

- in the first call `x == true` so it prints `0`.
- Then it sets `x = false`
- In future iteration `x == false` => so no more output.

You probably wanted something like

```
// only check this once since it isn't changed in the loop
// do not loop at all if button wasn't pressed
if(x)
{
    // Do all prints in a loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        print(i);    // prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    }

    // reset the flag so you do the printing only in the frame
    // where the button was pressed
    x = false;
}
```

---

And for Unity specific you might want to use [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) instead of `x`.

Comment: thanks! I'll try that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your for loop during the frame that the return key is released. This ensures that we don't run this for every frame that the key is down (I'm assuming you don't want that). To do this we just check with `Input.GetKeyUp` which returns a boolean when the specified key is released.

```
if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coroutine with Input.GetKeyDown and then do yield return.

For Example:

```
private bool _pause = false;

private void Start()
{
  StartCoroutine(FuncName());
}

private void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
  {
    _pause = !_pause;
  }
}

private IEnumerator FuncName()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    while (_pause)
    {
      yield return null;
      print (i);
    }
  }
}
```